# How to manage changes to an application that are being maintained in different branches?

Tags: git, release-management

I am using Git to develop and maintain my application.

My application is being used by 5 clients and each of them has their own configuration like the logo, some special features, configs etc.

Now I wrote a new component and I need to add this component to each client's instance, but I do not know how to do it properly.

Each of clients are on separate branch and I know it is bad choice.

If I need to update the application, I need to copy-and-paste the code to each client and push it to the repo.

I know it is very weak but how to do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't have branched the application to 5 different branches before you sealed the base. But if they haven't diverged too far you have three possibilities:

1. Apply your changes, create a patch (`git diff > patch`), reset (so you can check out) and apply that on the heads of your five branches (`git apply patch`),
2. fork a new branch from `master`, apply the changes there, commit and `git cherry-pick` that commit in each of your branches (to the same effect as 1), then delete that extra branch,
3. apply the change to `master` and then `git rebase` your branches on top of that. This has the advantage that the edit will be a single commit common to all five. [See here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/) for practical introduction into rebasing.

1 and 2 put independent copies of your new commit at the top of the five branches' histories. 3 attempts to squeeze a new commit before they forked. A side effect of the latter is that all commits from that date on have to be reconstructed anew, because one can't modify an existing commit's parent. The first push per branch to the repository after 3 will have to be forced. The details are all discussed in the linked document.

Beware that if you made some more drastical changes that would conflict with what you want to update then the three ways will fail in different manners and it's good to be prepared.

1. in its default setting would just immediately reject the patch, making no changes. You'd need to investigate further why it did not apply, or use the relatively safe `--reject` (read the manual first though).
2. would decorate the points of failure with `<<<<<<<` `=======` `>>>>>>>` just like a failed `git merge` and you'd need to resolve the conflicts and re-commit, or abort the operation (it gives you advice what commands to use).
3. would create some horrible looking conflict messages and you might ending updating several commits on the way. Again, `git` would try to be helpful as of how to proceed.

You always have `git reset --hard`, `git cherry-pick --abort` and `git rebase --abort` to help you if something goes wrong. If you don't feel too comfortable using them you can also make copies of the current state of each of your branches before doing changes to it (`git branch backup`) and take everything back by `git reset --hard backup`.